# Does a positive sequence $x_n$ whose limit is zero achieves suprimum achieves at finite value of $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am working on important question which is useful for my work. Say suppose we have a positive sequence whose limit is zero. Then I believe that supremum of $x_n$ over $n$ is achieved at some finite value of $n$. Please let me know if it is true. Give me a hint to prove it.

Comment: If $x_n>0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ then $x_n<1$ for all but finitely many $n$. So then...?

Comment: Pick any $k$ such that $x_k>0$. There exists some finite $i$ such that $x_n<x_k$ for every $n>i$ hence the supremum of the whole sequence $(x_n)$ is also the supremum of the finite set $\{x_n\mid n\leqslant i\}$. Since this set is finite, its supremum is actually a maximum, qed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of my favorite tricks. If a sequence $x_n$ has a limit, you can define a new sequence $\bar{x}$ on $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$ by setting

$$ \bar{x}_n = \begin{cases} x_n & n \in \mathbb{N} \\ \lim_{m \to \infty} x_m & n = \infty \end{cases} $$

$\bar{x}_n$ is a *continuous* function on the *compact set* $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$, and continuous functions defined on compact sets have all sorts of nice features.

For your problem, we use the fact that every supremum of such a function is, in fact, a *maximum*. Since, in your problem, $x_\infty$ can't be the maximum, the maximum occurs for some $x_n$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: All hail the extended reals/integers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true. Since the limit is $0$, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n<x_0$ for all $n\ge m$. Can any term be larger than $\displaystyle\max_{n\le m}x_n$?